# Pattern for parsing XML Elements of the same type under different Parent Elements?

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm looking to parse an XML file that could look something like this:

```
<Locations>
    <Location Name="California">
        <Location Name="Los Angeles">
            <Person Name="Harrison Ford"/>
        </Location>
    </Location>
</Locations>

<People>
    <Person Name="Jake Gyllenhaal" Location="Los Angeles"/>
</People>
```

So I'm building up a list of locations and people.  As a business rule a 'person' must be associated with a 'location' but this can be done in one of two ways.  Either by listing them as a child of a location element whereby they take on that parent location or by explicitly listing it when listed under the People element.  Right now I handle it something like this (without error checking of any kind).

```
public class Parser
{
    public void Parse(XElement xmlRoot)
    {
        IList<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        IList<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        var locationParser = new LocationParser();

        locations = locationParser.ParseLocations(xmlRoot.Element("Locations"), people);

        var peopleParser = new PeopleParser();

        people = peopleParser.ParsePeople(xmlRoot.Element("People"), locations);

        // Do stuff with XML read objects.
    }
}

public class PeopleParser
{
    public IList<Person> ParsePeople(XElement peopleRoot, IList<Location> locations)
    {
        var xPeople = peopleRoot.Elements("Person");
        var people = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var person in xPeople)
        {
            var locationName = person.Attribute("Location").Value;

            var location = locations.First(loc => loc.Name.Equals(locationName));

            people.Add(this.ParsePerson(person, location));
        }

        return people;
    }

    public Person ParsePerson(XElement person, Location location)
    {
        var personName = person.Attribute("Name").Value;

        return new Person(personName, location);
    }
}

public class LocationParser
{
    PeopleParser peopleParser = new PeopleParser();

    public IList<Location> ParseLocations(XElement locationRoot, IList<Person> people)
    {
        var xLocations = locationRoot.Elements("Location");
        var locations = new List<Location>();

        foreach (var location in xLocations)
        {
            locations.Add(this.ParseLocation(location, people));
        }

        return locations;
    }

    public Location ParseLocation(XElement xLocation, IList<Person> people)
    {
        var children = new List<Location>();

        foreach (var subLocation in xLocation.Elements("Location"))
        {
            children.Add(this.ParseLocation(subLocation, people));
        }

        var newLocation = new Location(xLocation.Attribute("Name").Value, children);

        foreach (var xPerson in xLocation.Elements("Person"))
        {
            people.Add(peopleParser.ParsePerson(xPerson, newLocation));
        }

            return newLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is to me 'ugly' and this is only a simple example of something that gets alot uglier as more dependent XML types are added.  Is this about as good as it gets or is there a way this could be rewritten for better separation of concerns?

Comment: I don't get your question. Or why a person is listed in one of two different ways, but essentially meaning the same.

Comment: The question is could this be parsed 'better' say for example keeping PeopleParser out of the LocationParser for example.  As to why a person can be defined in multiple ways is simply to add options.  I'm mostly looking at building my own parser for something that already exists so I have to follow the creators conventions.  Look for example at the Wix toolset where XML elements such as Components can be declared under a variety of different elements.

Comment: what information do you need to store in Location object beside a name? Is path also important (e.g: California/Los Angeles) ?

Comment: Location could be anything such as a top level of Apartment complex with an apartment a level below with a room a level below that.

Answer (score 1):

> could be rewritten for better separation of concerns?

If this is code which is going to grow and be extensible then I recommend the usage of `Interfaces` as contracts of operations. I believe that you *feel* that the code has similarities which can be exploited and by defining interfaces one can create a system which extends the code and allows for a generic processing of the data items regardless of their origination.

---

I see two different types which can be expressed by an enum such as

```
public enum eOperationType
{
    Person,
    Location
};
```

Each of those items is similar in that each have a name and an `eOperationType`. So let us express that as an interface. The contract will require that it return *what* it is `OpType`, a full name and must know how to process a target Xml node.

```
public interface IOperation
{
    string FullName { get; set; }
    eOperationType OpType { get; }
    void ProcessXml(XElement node);
}
```

So before we specify a `Person` class or `City` we need to provide contracts for those classes (and any future class which might *seamlessly* replace those in future processing. This contract will be our generic way of handling the classes regardless of their *type*. Note that the person or location can now specify other attributes which are distinct to that class in these interfaces, but will still share the common operations of `IOperation`.

```
public interface IPerson : IOperation
{

}

public interface ILocation : IOperation
{

}
```

What does that give us? We can now create a class which will take in an xml node and express it via the interface. Let us look at person

```
public class Person : IPerson
{

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public eOperationType OpType { get { return eOperationType.Person; } }
    public void ProcessXml(XElement node)
    {
        var attr = node.Attributes().First (atr => atr.Name == "Name");
        FullName = attr.Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

Now all we need is a generic method which will take in an IOperation and return an instance of the class we need. Here is that generic method:

```
public static class XmlOperations
{
    public static T GetData<T>(XElement data) where T : IOperation
    {
        var clone = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        clone.ProcessXml(data);

        return clone;
    }
}
```

Now in the trivial example we can get all people (later locations can be added) such as:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetData());

var People =
doc.Descendants(eOperationType.Person.ToString() )
   .Select (ele => XmlOperations.GetData<Person>(ele));
```

People is now Harrison and Jake:

[image]

So at this point we can create a Location class which implements ILocation. Since it too implements IOperation we can reuse the generic xml processing. From there we can take this base generic implementation and mold it anyway we want; but by specifying atomic operations, the interplay between code is increased and re-use is expanded thanks to the generalizing found in the contracts.

---

Here is the full linqpad program

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetData());

    var People =
            doc.Descendants(eOperationType.Person.ToString() )
               .Select (ele => XmlOperations.GetData<Person>(ele) );

    People.Dump(); // Linqpad extension to display data.

}

public static class XmlOperations
{
    public static T GetData<T>(XElement data) where T : IOperation
    {
        var clone = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        clone.ProcessXml(data);

        return clone;
    }
}


public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public eOperationType OpType { get { return eOperationType.Person; } }
    public void ProcessXml(XElement node)
    {
        var attr = node.Attributes().First (atr => atr.Name == "Name");
        FullName = attr.Value.ToString();
    }

}


public string GetData()
{
return @"<Data>
<Locations>
    <Location Name=""California"">
        <Location Name=""Los Angeles"">
            <Person Name=""Harrison Ford""/>
        </Location>
    </Location>
</Locations>

<People>
    <Person Name=""Jake Gyllenhaal"" Location=""Los Angeles""/>
</People>
</Data>";
}


public enum eOperationType
{
    Person,
    Location
};


public interface IOperation
{
    string FullName { get; set; }
    eOperationType OpType { get; }
    void ProcessXml(XElement node);
}

public interface IPerson : IOperation
{

}

public interface ILocation : IOperation
{

}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's a very thorough answer and while I'm still wrapping my head around everything that's going on here I like the ideas.  Now I just need to play with and see how I can get the locations to plug into the persons.

Comment: @Thermonuclear I didn't understand how you work with the data so I didn't implement the `Location` class; but by using interfaces and finding common properties and operations, the ability to have a `List<IOperation>` of all objects, (whether person or location) with each of items tied to an enum is a powerful thing to use in Linq queries.